# Heroku: How to install openjdk-8-jdk for non-java projects?

Tags: java, heroku

I'm deploying a Django/Python project on heroku, and I need the Java Runtime Environment for a dependency.

How can I install `openjdk-8-jdk` on heroku for this Python project?

I tried this buildpack with no luck https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the JVM buildpack to your app:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add -i 1 heroku/jvm
```

Then redeploy.

Comment: I don't see any mention of a `heroku/jvm` buildpack in the documentation (though there is this: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-jvm-common). Are you sure `heroku/jvm` will work? It's not necessary to give `https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-jvm-common.git`? **Edit:** Apparently you're the "JVM Platform Owner at Heroku". I guess this is legit.

Comment: Yea, i'm sure it will work :) I'll see about improving the documentation.

Comment: @codefinger Thank you! What version is this JDK? How can I specify it? If I only use a Python-wrapped java library, do I still need a pom.xml?

Comment: No pom.xml is required. Here is a list of default and supported versions https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#supported-java-versions