# Heroku: How to specify the path of JVM buildpack non-java projects?

Tags: java, django, heroku

I'm deploying a Django/Python project on heroku, and I need the java.exe path.

In one of my django/python scripts I have:

`...
owlready2.JAVA_EXE = "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_221\\bin\\java.exe"
...`

 This runs on my localhost, but since I want to deploy my project on heroku, I know I would need to have some version of java install on heroku. However, I don't know how to install java and then specify the java.exe path in my django/python script for deployment.

Comment: Have you experience with java?

Comment: Yes, I ran the "which java" command to get the path location of the java that was installed on Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Heroku, which is Linux, you won’t want a .exe. But you can add Java by adding the `heroku/jvm` Buildpack to your app

Comment: This is true, but it would be a lot more helpful if you provided instructions on how to do that and a link to the official documentation.

Comment: @Chris 

I navigate to the my local git repo for my Django app. Then following:
 1. I ran the command found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50063159/9865882 . 
 2. Next, I ran the "which java". This tells me where the java is located on my heroku app. Mine was
 /app/.jdk/bin/java
 3. Since, the .jdk folder is under my django project's folder, I did this: 
 BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
 followed by JAVA_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.jdk/bin/java') to specify the path to the java
Maybe this a more elaborate way, but this working is for me now.